# HP DL320-g4 Hard Drive

Tags: hp

I'm not much of a hardware guy, so i am sorry if the answer to this question is obvious.  I was recently able to accurire a DL320 server that i want to set up as a lab server.  The server came with 2 80 gig SATA drives, Segate Baracuda model 7200.9.  I would like to increase the size of the drives by putting in 2 1 Tb drives and setting those up as a RAID Array.

My question is, before i go out and purchase the drives,  can i put any SATA drives in this, or is there a specific type required by this server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never had a problem using non-HP drives in an HP system, despite HP's claims to the contrary. The only thing to look out for in these cases is the maximum size of drive supported by the firmware. I've had a few servers that didn't support drives larger than 500 GB. However, looking at the [quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12365_na/12365_na.html) for this model it looks like it supports up to 1.5 TB drives, so you should be in the clear.

Answer (score 2):

If it already has SATA drives in it, then you're probably fine.  With any kind of server, it's usually proprietary (or at least, rare) connectors that will get you.  I don't know of any manufacturers that use a custom drive firmware or anything of the sort to restrict what drives can be used.

Pull one of the drives and look at the connector.  If it looks like your run of the mill SATA hard drive, then just unscrew it and drop another drive in there.  I'd be really surprised if it didn't work.

Comment: +1 informative and succinct

I too would be surprised. If they're SATA drives it should work just fine. :)